# TestScheduler for generic Observable with RxJava

Tags: unit-testing, rx-java

I started using `TestScheduler`. Everything works fine with something like this:

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    //when
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    TestObserver<Long> subscriber = new TestObserver<>();

    //run
    Observable
            .interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
            .subscribeWith(subscriber);

    //check
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertEquals(200, subscriber.valueCount());
}
```

If I use this instead:

```
@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    //when
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    TestObserver<Long> subscriber = new TestObserver<>();

    //run
    Observable
            .interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribeWith(subscriber);

    //check
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertEquals(200, subscriber.valueCount());
}
```

the test fails because the subscriber is never called.

All the examples I found, use the `TestScheduler` with an `Observable.interval` and pass the scheduler to the factory method like I did in the first example.
The reason why I can't use this method is that in the real app the observables are not as simple as this one and I can't pass the scheduler.
I thought that setting the `Scheduler` like I'm doing it in the second example would be good but it looks like it isn't.

What's the right way to use a TestScheduler for more generic Observables?

Without using the TestScheduler I can successfully use these methods:

```
@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {
    //when
    Scheduler trampoline = Schedulers.trampoline();

    //run
    TestObserver<Long> test = Observable
            .interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(trampoline)
            .subscribeOn(trampoline)
            .test();

    //check
    test.await(3100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    assertEquals(3, test.valueCount());
}

@Test
public void test4() throws Exception {
    //when
    Scheduler trampoline = Schedulers.trampoline();

    //run
    TestObserver<Long> test = Observable
            .fromArray(1L, 2L, 3L)
            .subscribeOn(trampoline)
            .observeOn(trampoline)
            .test();

    //check
    assertEquals(3, test.valueCount());
}

@Test
public void test5() throws Exception {
    //when
    Scheduler trampoline = Schedulers.trampoline();

    //run
    TestObserver<Long> test = Observable
            .fromArray(1L, 2L, 3L)
            .subscribeOn(trampoline)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .test();

    //check
    test.awaitTerminalEvent();
    assertEquals(3, test.valueCount());
}
```

**EDIT**

no difference if I use

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    mScheduler = new TestScheduler();

    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(__ -> mScheduler);
    RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(__ -> mScheduler);
}

@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    //when
    TestObserver<Long> subscriber = new TestObserver<>();

    //run
    Observable
            .interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(mScheduler)
            .subscribeOn(mScheduler)
            .subscribeWith(subscriber);

    //check
    mScheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertEquals(200, subscriber.valueCount());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the standard schedulers you may use (for interval). It is also possible to overwrite other standard-schedulers.

```
RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> testScheduler);
```

**testScheduler** would be your TestScheduler. After setting the plugin, you can use advanceTime as in *test1*

Examples:

```
@Test
// fails because interval schedules on different thread then JUnit-Runner-thread -> fall through
void notWorkingTest1() throws Exception {
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    TestObserver<Long> subscriber = new TestObserver<>();

    Observable
            .interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribeWith(subscriber);

    //check
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertEquals(200, subscriber.valueCount());
}


@Test
// not working because interval will not be scheduled on virtual time -> JUnit-Runner-Thread will close because test observable emits on different thread
void notWorkingTest2() throws Exception {
    //when
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    //run
    TestObserver<Long> test = Observable
            .interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .test();

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    test.assertValueCount(200);
}

@Test
// runs sync. -> no JUnit-Runner-thread blocking needed
void workingTest() throws Exception {
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(s -> scheduler);

    TestObserver<Long> test = Observable
            .interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // executed on Schedulers.computation()
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .test();

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    test.assertValueCount(200);
}
```

Comment: This can't work first of all because I'm not using the computation scheduler. Anyway even if I override the other schedulers the result is equivalent to what I have in test2. I edited my question.

Comment: Please look at the documentation of interval(). There you will see, that interval uses a default scheduler. The default scheduler is computation. If subscriber is not called, you may have used another scheduler. So you would need to block the JUnit-Runner-Thread, that the method would not just fell through and discontinue the JVM.

Comment: I added an example for test2, which is working plus some explanation.